# How can I refund a game purchased on the Nintendo Switch eShop?

Tags: nintendo-switch

A few minutes ago, I accidentally purchased a game on the Nintendo Switch eShop. I have not launched the game, so it still has 0 hours played.

How can I refund a digital game purchased on the Nintendo Switch eShop?

Answer (score 18):

Nintendo [does not offer refunds for games or DLC purchased on the eShop](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1981/%7E/refund-request-for-downloaded-game-or-dlc-%28wrong-game%2C-didnt-like-game%2C):

> #### [Refund Request for Downloaded Game or DLC (Wrong Game, Didn't Like Game, Accidental Purchase)](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1981/%7E/refund-request-for-downloaded-game-or-dlc-%28wrong-game%2C-didnt-like-game%2C)
>
> **Situation:**
>
> Refund request for digital content purchased through a Nintendo Shop Channel. (For example, incorrect game or DLC was downloaded, content was purchased by accident, you didn't like the game.)
>
> **What to do:**
>
> - **We are unable to provide refunds or exchanges for mistaken purchases.**
> - Please be sure to read the game descriptions and check out the screen shots available through the Nintendo eShop before making purchases.

Comment: Nintendo’s customer support were willing offer me a one-time refund of Nintendo eShop credit, but clarified this was an exception and and wasn’t standard policy.

Comment: The funny thing is, when you buy something on the eShop, the receipt they send mentions a "right of withdrawal within 14 days after purchase" according to which Nintendo has to refund the purchase without requiring a reason to do so. I explained my circumstance immediately after a purchase (I bought the wrong version of the game), and customer support refused my claim stating that the moment I purchased the game, I agreed to give up on my right of withdrawal. It's a somewhat disgusting scheme, to be honest...

Comment: Two years later, I can confirm that my original refund was a one-time exception. When I recently called Nintendo to refund a different product, customer support cited my previous refund and denied my request.

Answer (score 2):

Nintendo does not offer refunds. However, customer support may. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Nintendo’s customer support were willing offer me a one-time refund of Nintendo eShop credit, but clarified this was an exception and and wasn’t standard policy.

Two years later, I called Nintendo to refund a different produced. Customer support denied it citing my previous refund.

Answer (score 0):

You can get refunds for games by calling Nintendo Customer Support. I made an accidental purchase, and regained my funds.